# Can't start Tomcat with -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, jmx, monitor

I'm trying to monitor Tomcat via JMX. I was testing it locally using jConsole. I'm using the following Java Options without authentication first:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8050
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

So it works fine but if I try to use authentication it doesn't allow me to start Tomcat:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8050
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=./conf/jmxremote.password.template
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=./conf/jmxremote.access
```

Could you please help me to make it work! What I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [tomcat monitoring documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html) makes mention that you need to have the permissions for the password file set to readable only by the user that tomcat is running as.  I can see you're running this in windows, and you've put the jmxremote files in your java installation, which is almost certainly accessible to all accounts on your machine.  I'd move them to the conf directory in your tomcat installation, and then check your permissions, and try again.

Comment: I've moved both jmxremote files into the conf directory in your tomcat installation as you suggested. I'm not sure what do you mean by "check your permissions"? I can tell you that inside the `jmxremote.access` file `monitorRole` set to `readonly`, inside `jmxremote.password.template` file `monitorRole` set to `password123`.

Comment: Those are the permissions you're giving external users to jmx.  I'm referring to the Windows permissions on your file.  You'll need to right click the file, choose properties, click 'Security', and ensure that for the jmxremote.password file, only the user who is running tomcat has Read access to that file.